# How to display unicode char on a Button label

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to set a button label text to a unicode char. It's not working.

```
bttn.text = "\uf0f6";

bttn.text = "&amp;#xf0f6;";
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it here https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/icon-fonts If it's icon did you set font file for it ?
Try set it with this

```
 bttn.set("text",String.fromCharCode(0xf0f6));
```